# How to get the current item of a viewpager in xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

Good day guys,
Please I am new to xamarin, I have been looking for a way to get the current item of a viewpager, I have searched on google and I saw that Java has ViewPager.getCurrentItem, I have tried this in xamarin Android but did not work.

Please if there is a way to get the current item of a viewpager just show me. Thanks.

Comment: Xamarin has example source of using a ViewPager, including using `CurrentItem` : https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/fb9d4ed266bdf68bb1f9fa9933130b285712ec82/ViewPagerIndicator

Comment: Exactly, solution delivered, cheers!

Comment: @SushiHangover thank you for your response, now in my MainActivity I have been able to get the currentItem ID, e.g. var ID = ViewPager.CurrentItem; this will give me the ID of the current displayed item. The problem now is if I swipe the viewpager it doesn't affect var ID = ViewPager.CurrentItem; it still remain the previous ID when the app was first loaded, please can you tell me exactly where I should put this code (var ID = ViewPager.CurrentItem; ) so that when I swipe the viewpager it gives me the current ID after swiping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem now is if I swipe the viewpager it doesn't affect var ID = ViewPager.CurrentItem; it still remain the previous ID when the app was first loaded, please can you tell me exactly where I should put this code (var ID = ViewPager.CurrentItem; ) so that when I swipe the viewpager it gives me the current ID after swiping.

You can get the current item by subscribing the `PageSelected` event of your `ViewPager`, for example:

```cs
viewPager.PageSelected += (vpsender, ee) =>
{
    Log.WriteLine(LogPriority.Debug, "CurrentItem:", viewPager.CurrentItem.ToString());
};
```